# How to get only the first value from a flags enum value and get it in the order they were added

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
[Flags()]
public enum Foo
{
    Unknown = 0x00,
    A = 0x01,
    B = 0x02,
    C = 0x04,
    D = 0x08,
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static List<Foo> AsList(this Foo types)
    {
        List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>();
        foreach(Foo sT in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Foo)))
        {
            if ((sT & types) == sT) list.Add(sT);
        }
        return list;
    }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo foo1 = Foo.A | Foo.B | Foo.C;
        Foo foo2 = Foo.C | Foo.B;

        Foo firstInfoo1 = foo1.AsList()[0];
        Foo firstInFoo2 = foo2.AsList()[0];
    }
}
```

Now `firstInfoo1` and `firstInfoo2` both come out be `Unknown` which i don't want. Seeing the code that is there should i return the index [1] always, as so : `foo1.AsList()[1]`?

Is that a good idea?? Any ideas on the error, bound checking that would need to be done.

Also lets have a look at foo2, i added `Foo.C` first and `Foo.B` second. Is there any way i can get from AsList `Foo.C` and not `Foo.B`, i.e. the first in order they were added.

Is that possible?

Appreciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: `0 & any == 0`, so `unknown` always will be returned

Comment: No, you can't determine the order, as the enum is stored as an integer number. `1 + 2 == 2 + 1 == 3`.

Comment: @Grundy, yes i understand that, that's why the question says should i return the index [1], the [0]th index will always be unknown

Comment: @Abhi i think better will be use `Unknown = 0x10` instead of `Unknown = 0x00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either remove the Unknown value, or do this:

```
if ((int)sT != 0 && (sT & types) == sT) list.Add(sT);
```

A little background: those OR-ed enums are not stored like that in memory, they are stored as a simple integer number, so .NET doesn't known how that enum was constructed.

Comment: Can you advise on the bounds checking that needs to be done in such cases : `Foo foo3 = Foo.Unknown;` `Foo example = foo3.AsList()[0];`

Comment: if ((int)types == 0) { list.Add(types); return; }

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude the `Foo.Unknown` element specificaly because `0 & x` will always be `0`

```
if ((sT != Foo.Unknown) && ((sT & types) == sT)) list.Add(sT);
```

It is not possible to preserve the order for enums. You would have to use a different type to do this (`List<Foo>`?).

Answer (score 1):

There're some points in your "AsList" realization (if you plan to add similar
extensions for some more enums):

1. You'd probably not eliminate List[0], but enum items that equals to 0
    if and only if the enum has [Flags] attribute
2. It's a good idea to remove all aliases

   For instance, for some enum:

> ```
> public enum Quantity {
>   Zero = 0,  // <- You probably want to preserve it
>   One = 1,
>   Many = 2,
>   ALotOf = 2 // <- You'd rather eliminate this alias
> }
> ```

And for another one

```
[Flags]
public enum Rigths {
  None = 0,          // <- You don't need it
  CanRead = 1,
  CanWrite = 2,
  CanDelete = 4,
  CanErase = 4,      // <- This alias is of no use
  CanEliminate = 4   // <- And this alias is of no use as well
}
```

A possible solution is

```
  public static class Extensions {
    private static long EnumToLong(Object value) {
      if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, value))
        return 0;

      Type type = value.GetType();

      if (!type.IsEnum)
        return 0;

      Type baseType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(type);

      if (baseType == typeof(long))
        return (long) (value);
      else if (baseType == typeof(ulong))
        return (long) ((ulong) value);
      else if (baseType == typeof(uint))
        return (long) ((uint) value);
      else if (baseType == typeof(int))
        return (long) ((int) value);
      else if (baseType == typeof(short))
        return (long) ((short) value);
      else if (baseType == typeof(ushort))
        return (long) ((ushort) value);
      else if (baseType == typeof(byte))
        return (long) ((byte) value);
      else if (baseType == typeof(sbyte))
        return (long) ((sbyte) value);

      return 0;
    }

    private static List<T> CoreAsList<T>(Enum value) {
      // Has [Flags] attribute?
      Boolean hasFlagAttribute = false;

      Object[] attrs = typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(true);

      for (int i = attrs.GetLowerBound(0); i <= attrs.GetUpperBound(0); ++i)
        if (attrs[i] is FlagsAttribute) {
          hasFlagAttribute = true;

          break;
        }

      List<T> result = new List<T>();
      HashSet<long> hs = new HashSet<long>();

      foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))) {
        long v = EnumToLong(item);
        long all = EnumToLong(value);

        if (hs.Contains(v))
          continue;

        hs.Add(v);

        if ((all & v) == v)
          if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), item))
            if (!((v == 0) && (hasFlagAttribute)))
              result.Add((T) item);
      }

      return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// You extension
    /// </summary>
    public static List<Foo> AsList(this Foo types) {
      return CoreAsList<Foo>(types);
    }
  }
```

As for order, you can't preserve it. As you can see, enum is in fact an integer:

```
  [Flags]
  public enum Options: long { // or byte, int, uint, short…
    Option1 = 0,
    Option2 = 1,
    OptionN = 1024  
  }
```

when ever you do something like

```
Options a = b | c
```

you loose the order since for integers

```
b | c == c | b
```